# Windows Phone - NavigationService through app.xaml.cs

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

I am making app, where if you cannot get response connection from the server, you are redirected to a special page, which tells you something like "you cannot use your app without internet connection".

I am using API requests through several pages and places and from all of them, I want the same - redirecting to that special page. (so I do not want to place try-catch with same behaviour whenever I call api request)

Right now, I am throwing exception and my idea is to "catch" that exception at

```
private void Application_UnhandledException(object sender,ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
```

Exception is throwed there, however now I do not know, how to redirect you from that point.

Also if you think, this is "not right", let me know too. However the app should be not operationable offline.

(I am using Windows Phone 8.0)

---

Edit : Well it is not possible to navigate from that point, the app drops :)

Comment: Have you _tried_ simply redirecting from there? That is, calling `NavigationService.Navigate()` from the unhandled exception callback - although you'll probably want to ensure you are on the UI thread before that: `Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => { NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/NetworkErrorPage.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute))})`

Comment: Sorry, didn't read your edit before posting the comment. Still, does the `BeginInvoke` help?

Comment: @jlahd - good point with dispatcher, however even if I do nothing and I comment any code in that method, the app drops. And if I want to use your method, I have to merge with another one (cause in app.xaml.cs you cannot use `NavigationService.Navigate`) : `Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => { (Application.Current.RootVisual as PhoneApplicationFrame).Navigate(new Uri("/NoConnection.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)); }));`

Comment: Do you set `e.Handled = true`? Without that, the system terminates the application.

Comment: @jlahd - tx, it really was it. However even if I set it true and I redirect it to that page, it looks like that it broke the app enough, that I can see that "noconnection page", however it does not react on anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            if (NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable())
            {
              your code....
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("no internet connection found...please check with your operator...");
            }
        }